# Internet access for Android apps converted for the Blackberry Playbook?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I created a "native" webworks app for the Blackberry Playbook and it required to have an url whitelist in the config.xml for accessing the internet.

Now, I converted my Android app, and I could not access the internet. How I could allow that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the VMWare VM must be setted with network in bridged mode, instead of NAT mode, as they [twitted here](https://twitter.com/#!/BlackBerryDev/status/169457484866654208).
In this way my app can pass the network check, but still can't access the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml? That's all you need, I think.